# Why google chrome is messing up my image

Tags: google-chrome

[image]

See that image, in Chrome you'll notice on each side (if you don't see it try boosting your brightness) in the inner of the circle some white lines but in Firefox it's all smooth

And the file don't have those white lines at all trust me.

Why Google's doing this?

I'm sure Chrome is compressing the image so it's pixelated and those white lines appears...

**Another post here**

https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/chrome/tk9jXCJR_2A/1fQ33HvOUPsJ

is having the same issue and he have an image to prove it.

Comment: it's not a white line, it's the edge of the image being cut off so you lose the outer pixels of the circle part of the image.

Comment: Look closely Marc inside the circle, it seems that chrome is compressing the image making it uglier.

Comment: I'm comparing it with Firefox. At maximum zoom they appear identical.

Comment: The problem shows up in Chrome 19.0.1084.52 m, but renders correctly in IE 8. I've uploaded a demonstration at http://imgur.com/hvgZ0 , the left circle is how it appears in Chrome, the middle circle is the same thing with some of the funny area marked in red, and the right circle is how the image is displayed in IE.

Comment: For me, it's the same for IE9, FF and Chrome. (with the white line)

Answer (score 1):

It may be that chrome is re-compressing in order to cut down on cache size. Maybe they're sharing some code with the mobile browser to optimize this, heh.

Have you tried the same image with PNG instead of jpg? It might survive recompression better.

Comment: I see the artifact in chrome at all zooms, but converting the image to PNG makes the artifact go away. Of course, you pay a small size cost for the lossless compression, but JPEG was always expected to do poorly on line art.